# How to search a folder of text files to see if a specific string exists and then extract a string between two words using Python?

Tags: python, output, python-unicode

Currently, I'm just trying to figure out why this code won't work.

EDIT: wrote some new code

EDIT 2: SOLVED (reading through comments reminded me to encode the with.open() so it looks like this now,

EDIT 3: New code for pulling the "string" (date) I need between two words.

```
import os
items=os.listdir("C:/output")


for names in items:
  if names.endswith(".txt"):
    with open('C:/output/' + names, encoding="utf8") as currentFile:
      text = currentFile.read()
      if ('Date Released' in text):
           a = 'Released'
           b = 'Description'
           startpos = text.find(a) + len(a)
           endpos = text.find(b, startpos)
           print('Date Released ' + text[startpos:endpos] + names + '\n')
           #print ('Found in ' + names[:-4] + '\n')
      else:
          print ('Not in ' + names[:-4] + '\n')
```

I'm now getting the output:

```
Date Released :  12/14/2016



1393-004IP_ B_ C2  filename

Date Released :  4/11/2017



1476-002 IP, filename

Date Released :  9/25/2015



1987-XXX IP filename
```

Is there a way to get the Date Released : #/##/#### line on the same line as the file name? Also, some output I get when I run this right now is garbage. I'm assuming it could be from checking for Date Released more than once or a possible flaw with the if condition?

Comment: with open("C:/output/result.txt", "w", encoding="utf8") as r:

did you try this?

Comment: Yes, I've tried "utf8" and "latin-1" just to see if either would fix it. I actually placed the encoding='code' in the open.read() statement, is that incorrect? IE:  with open('C:/output/' + filename, encoding='code') as file:

Comment: try "mbcs", helped me quite some times

Comment: Thank you HunkDivine ! I find it strange that the encoding didn't work with the other code I had... Nonetheless, I'm a step closer to the finish line! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with windows try using double "\" instead of  single"/" in path names